# 3 boys and six girls go to the theatre. The theatre gives out four free movie passes randomly.

Tags: probability

**a)** What is the probability that exactly two boys will get the passes?

I got ${}_{3}C_2/{}_{9}C_4$ but its wrong..

would the right answer be $({}_3 C_2/{}_{9}C_4)({}_{6}C_2/{}_{9}C_4)$

**b)** what is the probability of at least two girls getting passes?

is it:

$$1 - ({}_3 C_3/{}_9 C_4)({}_6 C_1/{}_9 C_4)$$
(only one girl)???

can some tell me if these answers are right?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

a)Probability that exactly two boys will get the passes:
$${{3C2*6C2\over9C4}={45\over126}}$$
You need to consider the girls also.
b)Probability of at least two girls getting passes
$${{6C2*3C2+6C3*3C1+6C4*3C0\over9C4}={120\over126}}$$

Comment: why can't you do 3C2/9C4 * 6C2/9C4? why do you have to put it under a common denominator?

Comment: 3C2∗6C2 is the number of ways in which 2 boys AND 2 girls can be chosen.

Comment: 9C4 is the total number of ways possible.

Comment: Probability=(Number of favorable events)/(Total Events)

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer for the first question :${3C2 \times 6C2}\over {9C4}$?
As for the second answer: $1-{{({3C3 \times 6C1})}\over {9C4}}$?

Comment: I dont know what the answer is, I was asking you. is it correct?

Comment: yes both are correct. for part (b) @Novice uses the complement i.e. girls get less than 2 passes.